# Height of ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout

Have LinearLayout with height=100dp. Need to dynamically add 5 ImageView, and they need to stay on 1 line and have same height.

When i do this on display size => 4.5' - all fine. But when i use AVD with 4' or 480 resolutin, last item is smaller.

Please help me find solution and sorry for my english!

Here most simplest code for add imageview:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
            image.setTag(imageNames[position]);
linearLayout.addView(image);
```

and here is container

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Comment: u need to post your layout and some code snippet or any image depicting your problem.

Comment: tried to use weight instead of height. ?

Comment: Use weight and it should work.

Comment: add some code, how u say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image views width and height is not set. therefore, will depend on screen and images resolutions.

**Code:**

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
image.setTag(imageNames[position]);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
linearLayout.addView(image);
```

Comment: why width is match parent?

Comment: height is match parent not width

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **`android:weightSum`** attribute in **`LinearLayout`** and **`android:weight`** in each ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** This type of code will probably shrink images in small screen sizes. So you could use **`LinearLayout`** with **`HorizontalScroolView`** instead